# How to enforce user to enter a datefield in DD-MM-YYYY format, and timefield in 'HH:MM' format in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

my models.py:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')
```

my forms.py:

```
class AttendancenameForm(ModelForm):
    teacher_name = forms.ModelChoiceType(queryset=Teachername.objects.all())
    date = /*** What should I write to enforce 'DD-MM-YYY'?***/
    intime = /*** to enforce 'HH:MM' format?***/
```

Please provide me suggestions to make it in above format otherwise, It has to raise error against entered input. How can I implement it in django forms?

I also want to calculate total hours based on intime and outtime, how can I implement it in my views.py file?

Answer (score 2):

`django.froms.DateField` and `django.forms.TimeField` both have an input parameter named `input_formats` which is a list of date and time input formats, respectively. They define what patterns should be attempted when parsing the user input.

```
date = DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'])
intime = TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M'])
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/# for details.

Comment: I've tried using 'input_formats' in my django forms.py file, but when I'm submitting values in my form it prompts me - 'Enter a valid date'. But I'm submitting a valid date as per the format I've specified. I don't know what's the problem exactly. Please suggest me how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a prompt from Javascript? Are you using the Django Widget for form rendering? I would guess the widget uses settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#date-input-formats), try setting this appropriately, same for settings.TIME_INPUT_FORMATS. I assume when you change this settings, the form field instances are using this too and you might not need to specify the `input_formats` parameters anymore. But I haven't tested this.